# How to interpret alias results while checking for collinearity in a Linear model in R?

Tags: r, alias

Being a new to R and modeling. I was working on linear model and saw NA for my model results. So I checked the attached post by Mark Needham [checking Co-Linearity using alias function](http://markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/18/r-linear-models-with-the-lm-function-na-values-and-collinearity/) . However, When I performed my aliasing I got -1 and 1. If any one can help me out with interpreting the results, that will be great help. In other words, Is it Ok to say that shuttle service is highly co-related with outdoor pool, but not with Mini bar and spa ? What does -1 and 1 mean ?

Below is my alias results:

```
Model :
sub1$Likelihood_Recommend_H ~ sub1$`Mini-Bar_PL` + sub1$`Pool-Outdoor_PL` + 
    sub1$Spa_PL + sub1$`Shuttle Service_PL`

Complete :
                           (Intercept) sub1$`Mini-Bar_PL`Y sub1$`Pool-Outdoor_PL`Y sub1$Spa_PLY
sub1$`Shuttle Service_PL`Y  0          -1                   1                      -1
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alias function finds linearly dependent terms in the linear model. So the way to interpret the numbers output by alias is:
Shuttle_service_PL = -1*Mini-bar_PL + 1*Pool-Outdoor_PL + 1*Spa_PL

Comment: Does it mean Shuttle service is dependent or correlated with Outdoor pool , but not with other two variables ?

Comment: Shuttle service is correlated with all 3 variables

Comment: then what does -1 and 1 mean ?

Comment: +1 and -1 are the coefficients of linear combination (dependency). Anything other than 0 in the alias output means the variables are linearly dependent!

Comment: How about +ve and -ve signs ? Can you please explain more about signs ?

Comment: Read my answer again. The signs refer to the signs of coefficients in the linear dependency.

Comment: Is it safe to interpret that shuttle service and Outdoor pool might be related with one another, but not the other variables ?

Comment: Shuttle service is linearly dependent on mini bar, outdoor pool and spa, all 3 variables.